# How to copy and store the position of an object / shape in PPT and then paste that position onto other objects in other slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm new to VBA coding, and I want to create two macros, one that stores an objects / shapes position, and another that allows me to paste that positioning onto other objects on any slide (including other slides). I think the issue I am running into is referencing the stored objects position from the other code, but I am very new to this so i could have just coded gibberish haha. Thanks!

```
Sub CopyPositon()
    
    Dim oshpR  As ShapeRange
    Dim T1     As Single
    Dim L1     As Single
    
    Set oshpR = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    
    T1 = oshpR(1).Top
    
    L1 = oshpR(1).Left

End Sub

Sub PastePosition()

    Set oshpR = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange

    oshpR.Left = L1

    oshpR.Top = T1

End Sub
```

Comment: There's a lot to be said for learning to do this yourself, but if you like, I have a free add-in (Windows desktop PPT only) that does this and several other useful things.  The add-in's called THOR and is available here http://www.pptools.com/free/FAQ00002-THOR-The-Hammer.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In VBE Insert>Module, paste the code.
- Run `CopyPositon` first, then run `PastePosition`

```
Public T1     As Single
Public L1     As Single
Sub CopyPositon()
    Dim oshpR  As ShapeRange
    Set oshpR = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    T1 = oshpR(1).Top
    L1 = oshpR(1).Left
End Sub
Sub PastePosition()
    Set oshpR = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    oshpR.Left = L1
    oshpR.Top = T1
End Sub
```

If you could keep a placeholder (assumes it is the first shape) on slide one as reference, you don't have to use public variable.

```
Sub SetPosition()
    Dim oshpR  As ShapeRange
    Dim T1     As Single
    Dim L1     As Single
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1)
            T1 = .Top
            L1 = .Left
    End With
    Set oshpR = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    oshpR.Left = L1
    oshpR.Top = T1
End Sub
```